# JNA not found. native methods will be disabled. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Native

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, swagger

I am preparing spring-boot application. Then I got the following error:

> ```
> JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Native
> ```

I am using swagger, elasticsearch, mariadb and maven for my project.

Log is given below:

```
11-02-2018 15:12:58 [o.e.env:120] internalInfo : [Araki] heap size [891mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
11-02-2018 15:12:59 [o.e.bootstrap:135] internalWarn : JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.Native
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Natives.<clinit>(Natives.java:45)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapInfo.isMemoryLocked(BootstrapInfo.java:44)
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.process.ProcessProbe.processInfo(ProcessProbe.java:130)
        at org.elasticsearch.monitor.process.ProcessService.<init>(ProcessService.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:104)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:47)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:886)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:43)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:201)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder$1.call(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:879)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.loadEagerSingletons(InjectorBuilder.java:193)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.injectDynamically(InjectorBuilder.java:175)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorBuilder.build(InjectorBuilder.java:110)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:93)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:213)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:140)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:143)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:150)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.createNodeClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.createClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:95)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.elasticsearchClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d451692f.CGLIB$elasticsearchClient$1(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d451692f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d856b189.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d451692f.elasticsearchClient(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at gobowlook.StoriesApplication.main(StoriesApplication.java:22)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:483)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
11-02-2018 15:13:00 [o.e.node:120] internalInfo : [Araki] initialized
11-02-2018 15:13:00 [o.e.node:120] internalInfo : [Araki] starting ...
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding jna jar file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Resource Link: 
[Org.elasticsearch.bootstrap - JNA not found. native methods will be disabled](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/org-elasticsearch-bootstrap-jna-not-found-native-methods-will-be-disabled/30030)

Answer (score 0):

For me belowworked when I executed below in kibana devtools console.

```
PUT your_index_name/_settings
    {
    "index": {
    "blocks": {
    "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
    }
    }
    }
```

I followed below link:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api/110282/4